# URLSessionDownloadDelegate progress not updating

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I'm quite new to the topic of IOS development, so it's may a stupid question, but I'm unable to calculate and print the progress of a download task using URLSessionDownloadDelegate.
I was following this guide: https://medium.com/swlh/tracking-download-progress-with-urlsessiondownloaddelegate-5174147009f and its source code  from https://github.com/ShawonAshraf/URLSessionProgressTrackerExample but the progress label just jumps from 0 to 100% even with bigger files, which require a few minutes to download.
If it's possible to do so, I would like not to use a third party lib.
I'm using swift 5 with Xcode 11.4 on an iOS 13.4 simulator.

Comment: “using URLSessionDownloadDelegate” You don’t need to. The download task has a `progress` property. So before you start, just say `myProgressView.observedProgress = task.progress`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sample project you've linked performs integer division to calculate the progress, and therefore only ever gives you 0 or 1 as the result.

Replace this line

```
let percentDownloaded = totalBytesWritten / totalBytesExpectedToWrite
```

with this

```
let percentDownloaded = Double(totalBytesWritten) / Double(totalBytesExpectedToWrite)
```